# Present SKStoreProductViewController with no animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storekit, ios-animations

I am trying to present an instance of `SKStoreProductViewController` **without** the animation.

Snippets of the code from the view controller StoreKit is presenting from:

**Objective-C**

```
SKStoreProductViewController *storeProductVC = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
[storeProductVC loadProductWithParameters: <PARAMETERS> completionBlock: nil];

[self presentViewController: storeProductVC animated: NO completion: nil];
```

**Swift**

```
let storeProductVC = SKStoreProductViewController()
storeProductVC.loadProduct(withParameters: <PARAMETERS>, completionBlock: nil)

self.present(storeProductVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Passing in `NO` for the `animated` flag did not work. The StoreKit view controller still presented with animation. I know the theme of Apple frameworks is to allow minimal customizations, but I am hoping this isn't the case.

Comment: You call `present` inside the completion block of `loadProduct`.

Comment: That does not solve my issue. And it is more of an UX decision whether to present `SKStoreProductViewController` in the completion block or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can present it without animation in a separate UIWindow.

**Objective-C**

```
SKStoreProductViewController *storeProductVC = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
[storeProductVC loadProductWithParameters: <PARAMETERS> completionBlock: nil];

UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];

// Note: storeKitWindow should be strongly held, i.e. a property
self.storeKitWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: mainScreen.bounds];
self.storeKitWindow.screen = mainScreen;
self.storeKitWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
self.storeKitWindow.rootViewController = storeProductVC;

[self.storeKitWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
```

**Swift**

```
let storeProductVC = SKStoreProductViewController()
storeProductVC.loadProduct(withParameters: [:], completionBlock: nil)

let mainScreen = UIScreen.main

// Note: storeKitWindow should be strongly held, i.e. a property
storeKitWindow = UIWindow(frame: mainScreen.bounds)
storeKitWindow.screen = mainScreen
storeKitWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar
storeKitWindow.rootViewController = storeProductVC

storeKitWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
```